# Android: Clear old activity instance from history stack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have the following simple scenario:

- One Activity called **ListCarsActivity.kt** where list of cars are displayed. When the user click on the FloatingActionButton, it opens another activity called **AddCarActivity.kt**
- When the user click on the **Add Car** button, I start a new intent to go to the initial activity ListCarsActivity.kt where the added car is now displayed.

**Problem**: From now, when I click on the Back button, the ListCarsActivity is displayed a second time.

How to clear the old entry of ListCarsActivity from the History stack?

[image]

Comment: Open **AddCarActivity** with **startActivityForResult()** and when **AddCar** button is clicked pass the **intent** (not a new intent) and close the **AddCarActivity **and inside your** AddCarActivity's onActivityResult** the intent data will be available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your **AddCarActivity.kt** Activity like below inside your **ListCarsActivity.kt**

```
val intent = Intent(mContext, AddCarActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1); //Use any request code
```

Now for the above code what startActivityForResult do is that it is an intent to receive data back from some other activity or source(like camera, contacts, etc)

Now when all the work is done in your **AddCarActivity.kt** you can all the below **intent** to get the result back

```
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                intent.putExtra("key", data); // if you wanted to get data 
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
```

And inside your **ListCarsActivity.kt** you need to add **onActivityResult** which will get the data from **AddCarActivity.kt**

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) { //Your request code here
                Object obj = data.getParcelableExtra("key");
                 //Do as per your needs

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With this, if you wanted to return the newly added data back in the first activity it can be fetched without the usage of any third-party libs.

Try it and do let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

use `finish()` after `startActivity(intent)` to finish the activity in which you are starting another activity

Answer (score 0):

You should run `AddCarActivity` with `startActivityForResult` method, and then you have to set result with `setResult` method in `AddCarActivity` which returns you to `ListCarsActivity` without starting it again

Official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is valid and will work as you want. However, I would like to a bit more information here.

In your `ListCarsActivity`, on clicking the `floatingButton`, you are starting a new activity `AddCarActivity`. Once done, on clicking the button **"Add Car"**, you can rather do your save/post logic and close (`finish()`) this (`AddCarActivity`).

Doing this will prevent you from relaunching the same activity (`ListCarsActivity`) again. Also, If you close (`finish()`) the `ListCarsActivity` and if the user presses `back` from the `AddCarActivity`, the app will close (considering there are only two activities). This is definitely what you don't want.

Rather, you can implement `onResume` method in your `ListCarsActivity` to refresh the list with new and updated data. This same function will be called once the user clicks on **"Add Car"** and the `AddCarActivity` is closed. Hence, there would be no need to startActivity again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `ListCarsActivity` again when user add the car button just put `finish()` Because your first activity, you've just started the activity `ListCarsActivity.kt` not the finished yet so, it's already in stack. If you will call again `ListCarsActivity.kt` then in your stack your activity opened two times.